# Keep getting error when trying to send email with firebase functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

Anybody able to help? This always gives me an error. Any advice? I get the following error: Error: could not handle the request. I have removed sensitive information.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey("API KEY"); /*PLACEHOLDER KEY*/

const cors = require('cors')({
  origin: ['https://DOMAIN.co.uk'], 
  methods: ['POST', 'OPTIONS'],
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type'],
  preflightContinue: false,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 204
});



exports.sendEmailConfirmation = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  
  cors(req, res, () => {
    
    return Promise.resolve()
      .then(() => {
        if (req.method !== 'POST') {
          const error = new Error('Only POST requests are accepted');
          error.code = 405;
          throw error;
        }
  
        const message = {
          to: 'email@email.com',
          from: 'email@email.com',
          subject: 'subject',
          text: 'some text',
          html: 'some html'
        };
    
        return sgMail.send(message);
        
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.body) {
          res.send(response.body);
        } else {
          res.end();
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        return Promise.reject(err);
      });
      
  });
  
});
```

It loads normally using functions, and shows no errors on there, I can't work out why it is not working.

Many thanks in advice

Comment: Can you show us the error you get ?

Comment: Error: could not handle the request